# C++ OpenMP object counter incorrect counts with std::vector of objects

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I need a threadsafe counter for the number of current objects of type `Apple`.  I have tried to make a simple one with OpenMP, but I don't understand why the counting is incorrect.  Here is a simplification of the class, with actual test code and actual output:

**Class**

```
class Apple {

public:

    Apple();
    ~Apple();
    static int getThreadCount();

private:

    static int threadCount;
    void threadCountIncrease();
    void threadCountDecrease();

};

Apple::Apple() {
    threadCountIncrease();
}

Apple::~Apple() {
    threadCountDecrease();
}

void Apple::threadCountIncrease() {
    #pragma omp critical(AppleThreadCount)
    {
    std::cout << "## COUNT ++" << "\n";
    ++threadCount;
    }
}

void Apple::threadCountDecrease() {
    #pragma omp critical(AppleThreadCount)
    {
    std::cout << "## COUNT --" << "\n";
    --threadCount;
    }
}
```

**Test code**

```
std::vector<Apple> apples;
cout << Apple::getThreadCount() << "\n";
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    apples.push_back(Apple());
    cout << Apple::getThreadCount() << "\n";
}
```

**Output that I don't understand**

```
## COUNT ++
## COUNT --
0
## COUNT ++
## COUNT --
## COUNT --
-1
## COUNT ++
## COUNT --
## COUNT --
## COUNT --
-3
## COUNT --
## COUNT --
## COUNT --
```

Why are there more "COUNT --" occurrences than "COUNT ++" occurrences?  Why is the last shown count -3 instead of 3?

---

Thanks to the accepted answer, I ultimately discarded what I was doing in favor of [this solution](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/counting-objects-in-c/184403484).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first want to note that my explanation might not completely technical correct.

One thing that happens is that when you do `apples.push_back(Apple());` then a *copy* of your element is created. Because you have not defined a copy constructor the `threadCountIncrease` is not called for this *copy*.

So you will end up in at least twice as many `--` then `++`.

In addition to this the `std::vector` will - when it size increases - need to allocate more memory. Depending on the implementation this will result in a reallocation or in a copy of the data. In your case an additional *copy* does occur.

When you add a `apples.reserve(10);` right before you loop you will see that the `--` count will decrease, because the `std::vector` already reserved the space for at least `10` elements.